# How to get rid of link effects on image links

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

I'm styling links with a box shadow:

```
a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 rgba(100, 149, 237, .6);
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

However, I can't get rid of it when the linked item is an image instead of text. I've tried removing it by styling a img, styling all images, !important, etc. I've even tried completely deleting the visited, hover and active states.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't style an element based on its contents as there is no parent selector.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: place example markup of img

Comment: Here is the img style that doesn't work:

    a img {
 box-shadow: none;
    }

Comment: You **can't** do what you are trying to do with CSS. You can't select upwards in the DOM.

Comment: What about styling the img? Why doesn't that work?

img {
 box-shadow: none;
}

Comment: You haven't applied those styles **to** the image in the first place to remove them

Comment: Good point. So how do I get rid of the box shadow on an image link?

Comment: Without JS, **you can't**. You might want to rethink adding those styles to all links in the first place.

Comment: Something to consider. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulie_D, @maioman, there is a way to do this after all—with the not selector. Create a class such as the following. It doesn't even need selectors:

`.imagelink {
}`

Apply it to any link that uses an image, then style links this way:

`a:link:not(.imagelink) {
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#0065FF;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #96D4FF;
 border-radius:5px;
}`

Easier than JS or applying a class to every link in the site.